# angular bootstrap datetimepicker not woking properly

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap-calendar

In angular bootstrap datetimepicker choose date of previous month and datepick again then current month is displayed in popover

[image]

When I change the date, I get an error in the console.

[image]

I followed this link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-datetimepicker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-time-picker%2Fdate-time-picker.component.ts

Comment: Have you declared     @ViewChild(NgbDatepicker)  private dp: NgbDatepicker;??

Comment: Yes I have used   @ViewChild(NgbDatepicker) 
  private dp: NgbDatepicker;

Comment: console.log(this.dp);   value get undefined

Comment: this.dp.navigateTo({ year: this.datetime.year, month: this.datetime.month });   this line not working